# Using dd() function in Laravel

Tags: laravel, dump

While using dd() function in Laravel, if my output looks like this,

```
Collection {#194 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => Post {#195 ▶}
    1 => Post {#196 ▶}
    2 => Post {#197 ▶}
  ]
}
```

what are the meanings of the codes, such as #194, #195, etc? Are they helpful in any way?

Comment: i never noticed that, good question, but it was not useful to me till now

Comment: Or you should use `print_r()` like (i.e `print('<pre style="color:red;">');
print_r($rslt);
print('</pre>');
exit;`)

Comment: #194, #195 are key of object https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39011241/laravel-dd-function-limitations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to **VarDumper** documentation - that's what **dd()** uses behind the hood:

```
#14 is the internal object handle. It allows comparing two consecutive dumps of the same object.
```

Depending on whether the item being dumped is an object or PHP resource, you'll see **#** for **objects** and **@** for **resources** in there. The number you're seeing after **#** is the ID assigned by the VarDumper to that object. It's displayed so that you can easily identify dumps for the same object, if you dump it multiple times.