# How to use dd() without stopping the program on laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a website with laravel, i want to debug my program but it's hard to use dd() since it will immediately stop the program, i want to make it show line by line per execution, any idea? any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You can use [`dump`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-dump). The function `dd` is a wrapper around "dump and die"

Comment: Hi, use XDEBUG for profiling and so on

Comment: If you want breakpoints, then XDebug is the way to go. `dd()` is useful, but inherently stops execution, "dump and **die**". You can also use `Log::info()` statements to log stuff as your code executes.

Comment: You can use core PHP function echo() or print_r() for more see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73430068/7186739

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73430068/7186739

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [dump](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-dump) as stated on the comment, but there's another way of logging that already wrapped as laravel class [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging), if you want to debug you can use one of the variant from there `Log::debug('An informational message.');`

Answer (score 6):

Another way to get your result without outputting to the page (useful for production at times) is to log it to a file. Laravel has Monolog built in, so use

```
Log::info($data);
```

and it will write the result to a file in `storage/logs` within your project folder.

Comment: This solution also has the benefit that changes to the session are not reversed. This happens if you are debugging using dd();

Answer (score 1):

As others stated: `dd` means `dump & die`. So it dumps the result and stops the excecution.

There is a shorter alternative which is `dump` and it doesn't kill the excecution.
Could also use `print_r`