# Laravel Dump, Die dd() not showing the full result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have noticed that when i use `dd()` in my Laravel application with a big amount of data thet the result is shown like this [...2] isted of being able to show the actual array

[image]

if I load only a small amount of data this does not happen, any solution to allow me to load the full data?

Comment: try to use print_r() with die or write echo '<pre>'; print_r($aa); die;

Comment: thanks @PHPGeek but i want to use dd() as it is more cleaner to navigate the data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39011241/laravel-dd-function-limitations

Comment: use `toArray()` to view full array data only

Comment: @silentwasd this didn't work as im using Laravel 7

Comment: @A.ANoman how do i use this to display similar to dd()